# Simple Batch file to delete the same 3 files held in many different DIRS

Tags: batch-file

I need to remove the same three files, lets call them:

- 1 (internet shortcut)
- 1_2.txt
- 1_2.html

These files have been creaetd 1,000s of times in different folders on the same set of networks drives.

I need a bat script that will delete them, permanently (without using Recycle Bin) and do it silently.

Any takes?
Thanks
Pappaslim.

Answer (score 0):

well... you could *try* this.... but use dir not del the first time to be sure you are deleting the right stuff...

```
for %%j in (C E F) do (for %%l in (1.lnk 1_2.txt 1_2.html) do (for /f %%i in ('dir /s /b %%j:\%%l') do (del /q %%i)))
```

where C E and F are your drives, and 1.lnk 1_2.txt and 1_2.html are your files.

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd "start_directory_of_subtree"
del /s "1 (internet shortcut)" "1_2.txt" "1_2.html" >nul
popd
```

Use with extreme caution.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off

FOR /R [C:\] %%G IN (1.lnk) DO DEL /Q %%G
FOR /R [C:\] %%G IN (1_2.txt) DO DEL /Q %%G
FOR /R [C:\] %%G IN (1_2.html) DO DEL /Q %%G

PAUSE
```

You should be cautious in using this.

NOTES:

"C:\" can be replaced with the drive letter of your network drive.

"1.lnk" can be replaced with whatever file extension is associated with your shortcut. I assumed .lnk but since you didn't list the file extension in your question I will let you fill it in.

Comment: Hi WhoFama24

Tried that but getting errors:
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: My post was not clear. Do NOT include the "[]" on the drive path. If your path contains spaces, enclose it in quotes (this is usually good practice but not always necessary). 

Example:
FOR /R "C:\Users\My User\Documents\Files To Delete" %%G IN (1.lnk) DO DEL /Q %%G